# Logical Equivalence: $\exists x((P(x) \land \lnot Q(x))\Leftrightarrow R(x)) \iff (\forall xP(x)\Rightarrow \exists y(Q(y) \lor R(y)))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am trying to show LHS equivalent to RHS however, but I am unsure on this specific example.

Any help would be appreciated.

$$\exists x((P(x) \land \lnot Q(x))\Rightarrow R(x)) \iff (\forall xP(x)\Rightarrow \exists y(Q(y) \lor R(y)))$$

Comment: What did you try thus far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You have to remove $\to$ with the equivalence : $p \to q \equiv \lnot p \lor q$; then "move inside" the negations.

Answer (score 1):

We will apply the principle that two sentences are equivalent iff they are false in precisely the same situations. One could also say that we show the negations to be equivalent.

Instrumental to achieving this is the equivalence:

$$\neg(\phi\to \psi) \iff \phi \land \neg \psi$$

---

Thus:
\begin{align*}
&\neg\exists x\,((P(x) \land \neg Q(x))\to R(x))\\
\iff&\forall x \,\neg((P(x) \land \neg Q(x))\to R(x))\\
\iff& \forall x\,(P(x) \land \neg Q(x) \land \neg R(x))
\end{align*}
Similarly:
\begin{align*}
&\neg(\forall x \,P(x) \to \exists y\,(Q(y)\lor R(y)))\\
\iff&\forall x\, P(x) \land \neg(\exists y\,(Q(y)\lor R(y)))\\
\iff&\forall x\, P(x) \land \forall y\, (\neg Q(y) \land \neg R(y))\\
\iff&\forall x\, P(x) \land \forall x\, (\neg Q(x)\land \neg R(x))\\
\iff&\forall x\,(P(x) \land \neg Q(x) \land \neg R(x))
\end{align*}